# How to build specific resource routes in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I want to never be able to delete a `Foo`.  How can I configure `resources :foos` to not create the delete route?

Also, `foos` belong to `bars` and should only be shown on the `bars` show page.  I've tried the following `get` routes but I get the associated errors:

```
get "/foos/:id"

ArgumentError at /bars/1220
missing :controller
```

--

```
get "/foos"

ArgumentError at /bars/1220
missing :action
```

--

```
get "foos/show"

No route matches [GET] "/bars/1220"
```

(There is most definitely a route for this, and it works if I leave `resources :foos` in the routes.rb file.)

I've read routing from the outside in a couple times but I guess I'm not getting it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify which of the standard routes to include when you use the `resources` command, with the `except` and `only` options:

```
resources :foo, :except => [:destroy] do
end
```

or

```
resources :foo, :only => [:index, :create, :show] do
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a delete route from being created do this:

```
resources :foos, :except => :destroy
```

With respect to your second question (if I understand it correctly), you have to use nested resources:

```
resources :bars do
  resources :foos, :except => :destroy
end
```

This will create many routes including:

```
/bars/:bar_id/foos/:id
```

Comment: Thanks @amb110395.  Very helpful for me going forward.